# Displaying image in HTML and JSP code

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

How can I display image from database in HTML and JSP code? I wrote this code in JSP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>MindDotEditor posted Data</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
        <link href="../sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../fckeditor.gif" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>

<%
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample";
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String id = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
    int j = Integer.parseInt(id);

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Image_File FROM Images WHERE Image_id = '3' ");
        int i = 1;
        if(rs.next()) {
            Blob len1 = rs.getBlob("Image_File");
            int len = (int)len1.length();
            byte[] b = new byte[len];
            InputStream readImg = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
            int index = readImg.read(b, 0, len);
            System.out.println("index" +index);
            stmt.close();
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("image/jpg");
            response.getOutputStream().write(b,0,len);
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }
%>

        <br>
        <center><input type="button" value="Print" onclick="window.print();return false;" /></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Images in HTML are to be represented using the `<img>` element. The `<img>` element has a `src` attribute which should point to an URL which returns an image. That URL can in this particular case just point to a `Servlet` which gets an `InputStream` of the image from some datasource (e.g. from local disk file system using `FileInputStream`, or from the DB using `ResultSet#getBinaryStream()`) and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the response the usual [Java IO](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) way.

Thus, you basically need to change your HTML to include the following:

```
<img src="images?id=1">
```

Then create a `Servlet` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/images` and implement the `doGet()` roughly like follows:

```
Image image = imageDAO.find(Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("id")));

response.setContentType(image.getContentType());
response.setContentLength(image.getContentLength());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + image.getFileName() + "\"");

BufferedInputStream input = null;
BufferedOutputStream output = null;

try {
    input = new BufferedInputStream(image.getInputStream());
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

That should be it.

I of course assume that the `image` table in your database already has the (self-descriptive) columns `content_type`, `content_length` and `file_name`, otherwise you'll need to substitute the first with `"image"`, leave the second away (or replace with `Blob#length()` if the database in question supports it) and hardcode a (random) name for the third.

Another (slightly different and covering error handling) examples of such an `ImageServlet` can be found in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html).

Answer (score -1):

you have to use another method [inline images](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/):

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAO...." width="16" height="14" alt="embedded folder icon">
```

make sure to base64 encode it. it will not work with ie6 or ie7 but should be fine with all other browsers